# Interspire to Magento migration

Tags: php, import, magento, shopping-cart

I recently started with Magento and decided to migrate Interspire shopping cart I already made time ago to it. At first look Magento seems a very huge beast - lots of options, maybe lack of simplicity resulting in some performance loss. I've got user guide from which I am not getting much of benefit since there're just descriptions of very ordinary tasks that I could easily discover myself by poking around frontend/backend. So my first tasks are category and product export. Interspire seems to be exporting ONLY products in three available formats:

1. Default
2. MYOB
3. Peachtree accounting

I did some searching on Magento's product importing and found a blog post which says that I should create a few sample products with all the necessary attributes myself and then start the import. But what should I do with categories ? Is it possible to import them or instruct Magento to automatically create categories when importing product file if unknown category is encountered ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advertisements folks ! though I would prefer an advice how to do it myself. I found out that I can do it for **free**, since Interspire supports Interspire -> OsCommerce migration and there's free OsCommerce -> Magento migration module in Magento Connect, only thing I need to do is to setup temporary OsCommerce on public server.